# Filtrar arrays e armazenar valores em outros arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Estou com um array de quatro posições, chamado de `arrValues`. **Cada** posição desse array, possui outros arrays. Por exemplo, no índice 0 do `arrValues`, se tem:

```
0: [95.321, 1642511]
1: [92.331, 1642515]
2: [98.612, 1642481]
.
.
.
(e assim por diante, podendo ter mais índices)
```

Pegando o exemplo acima, cada posição trás dois valores. Um do tipo `number` (índice 0) e outro do tipo `Date` (índice 1). Só que o me interessa são os valores do índice 1.

Fiz um `forEach` em cima do `arrValues`, e com ele pude ver os quatro arrays:

```
arrValues.forEach(function(value,index) {

}
```

Dentro desse forEach, fiz um outro forEach pro `value`. Ele é cada uma posição do array (como no exemplo mais acima).

```
arrValues.forEach(function(value,index) {

  value.forEach(function(valueOfValue, index) {
    
    // Pegando apenas o índice 0 de cada posição do array
    var numberOfValue = valueOfValue[0];

    // Por exemplo, armazena o valor 95.321
  }
}
```

A intenção é ter um array como o `arrValues`. Onde se tem quatro posições, e em cada uma dessas posições, o array ter apenas um único valor. Descartando o do tipo `Date` que fica no índice [1].

Dentro do forEach de `value`, utilizei um array novo que foi criado. E pra cada posição dele, instanciava um `Array` e ir inserindo com a função `push()` cada dado.

```
arrValues.forEach(function(value,index) {

  value.forEach(function(valueOfValue, index) {
    
    // Pegando apenas o índice 0 de cada posição do array
    var numberOfValue = valueOfValue[0];

    // Por exemplo, armazena o valor 95.321
    
    // Declarando que em tal posição, aí vai estar um array
    arrAux[index] = [];

    // Inserindo com .push, cada valor encontrado no indice 0
    arrAux[index].push(numberOfValue);
  }
}
```

Só que não tá dando o resultado esperado (pelo menos em como a lógica tá funcionando na cabeça). Quando vou exibir o `arrAux`, nele só tem um único valor.

Pra visualização:

```
 (Via exibição no console do navegador) 
 arrValues:
 
 > 0: (14) [Array(2), Array(2), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
 > 1: (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]       (tendo 2 arrays dentro dele)
 > 2: (14) [Array(2), Array(2), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
 > 3: (14) [Array(2), Array(2), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
```

Na posição 1, temos:

```
1: Array(2)
 > 0: (2) [18.10692687037037, 1642510800000]
 > 1: (2) [18.396871285714287, 1642514400000]
```

O objetivo é:

```
arrAux:
 
 > 0: (14) [Array(1), Array(1), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
 > 1: (2) [Array(1), Array(1)]       (tendo 2 arrays dentro dele)
 > 2: (14) [Array(1), Array(1), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
 > 3: (14) [Array(1), Array(1), ...] (tendo 14 arrays dentro dele)
```

```
1: Array(2)
 > 0: (2) [18.10692687037037]
 > 1: (2) [18.396871285714287]
```

Acredito estar usando lógica que não se encaixa no objetivo, ou posso estar fazendo de forma mais complicada e existir soluções mais simples. Já tô travado nisso faz um tempo, qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda e qualquer dúvida vou respondendo

Comment: Isso está muito confuso. Não subestime o leitor contando o problema como narrativa, seja descritivo e objetivo. Não faça isso de dizer que tem uma variável e depois mostrar apenas o dump parcial, mostre a declaração da variável com respectivo valor. Esclareça o quer fazer. Mostre o que está fazendo como um [mcve] que possa imediatamente ser copiado e testado por qualquer leitor. Mostre o resultado que obteve. Mostre o resultado que deseja obter

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que você quis dizer é que tem um `array`, cujos elementos são outros `arrays`. E que nesses `arrays` internos, você tem dois valores: números e datas, dos quais você quer apenas o número (que está na primeira posição), tente usar a seguinte estratégia:

Execute uma função que percorra o `array` principal e para cada elemento (que também é um `array`), execute uma função em que o retorno desta é o primeiro elemento daquele.

No javascript, você pode usar a função `map`, que aplica um processamento para cada elemento da coleção e cujo retorno é acrescentado num array de retorno.

```js
arrValues = [
  [
    [1, 'aaaaa'],
    [2, 'bbbb'],
  ],
  [
    [10, '++++'],
    [20, '----'],
    [30, '****'],
    [40, '!!!!']
  ], 
  [
    [100, '@@@@']
  ],[
    [1000, '####'],
    [2000, '%%%%'],
    [3000, '::::'],
    [4000, '||||'],
    [5000, '~~~~']
  ]
]

arrFinal = arrValues.map(function(arrayInterno){
  return arrayInterno.map(function(arrayUltimoNivel){
    return arrayUltimoNivel[0]
  });
})

console.log(arrFinal)
```

Comment: Cara, tu é um gênio, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado mesmo, de verdade!

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui pra ajudar. Abraço